# Windows batch variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have problem with getting value from variable trought two other variable. May sound complicated cause my english is not best.

I use variable rXY, to make xy grid, where X is x pos and Y is y pos. I filled grid with random chars but now I want to get value of one point.

echo %r23% will work, but if I ask coordinates from user (set /P p_x=) then
echo %r%p_x%%p_y%% will not work.

Is it even possible to get value this way?

Example of code:

```
echo off
cls
FOR /L %%Y IN (1,1,4) DO (FOR /L %%X IN (1,1,4) DO set r%%X%%Y=.)

echo Y
echo 4 %r14% %r24% %r34% %r44%
echo 3 %r13% %r23% %r33% %r43%
echo 2 %r12% %r22% %r32% %r42%
echo 1 %r11% %r21% %r31% %r41%
echo 0 1 2 3 4 X

set /P input=Please enter X and Y pos:
set p_x=%input:~0,1%
set p_y=%input:~1,2%
echo X=%p_x%
echo Y=%p_y%
echo [2,3]=%r23%

echo %r%p_x%%p_y%
pause
```

Comment: Normally, I'd post a long rant about how you should simply use arrays. But given you're programming this in batch... you can't have arrays, but you have my sympathy.

Comment: Yeah I know how to use arrays but I have little challenge here and I have to use batch this time

Comment: Unrelated hint: `@echo off` instead of using `cls`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the (horrible) **delayed expansion**.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo !r%p_x%%p_y%!
```

`%variables%` are expanded when the line is parsed, `!variables!` – at the time of actual execution.

Comment: Don't forget `endlocal`. Also, you can call a sub (end the sub with `goto :eof`) and do your variable magic there without having to bother with delayed expansion ;)

Comment: @STATUS: Okay, how would you do it without delayed expansion? (Also, `endlocal` is automatic when reaching the end of the script.)

Comment: the OS also frees memory when a process exits, yet we try to free all resources before that happens ;) ... edited the answer, see above (well, when it gets approved).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the delayed expansion differently:

```
CALL ECHO %%r%p_x%%p_y%%%
```

Hardly less horrible, but at least spares you the need to issue the special command (still, questionable advantage, to be honest).

How it works. The double `%` evaluates to the literal `%`, then the two variables are evaluated to their values, and lastly you have one more double `%` which is processed accordingly.

This is the first parsing that occurs immediately before executing the line. By the time of execution the line takes the form of (for example) `CALL ECHO %r21%`.

As you can guess, when the `CALL` command is invoked, the second parsing takes place, and this time `%r21%` is rigtfully evaluated to its respective value.

Comment: Both ways working but I'm not sure which one is better. Since it isn't important to save resource this time I prefer this one cause it's only one line long. Ty everybody!

Comment: The `call` version is very slow, and not secure against special characters, delayed expansion is safe for **special character** content

Comment: @jeb: Neither seems to be an issue with the OP's case. Still, that's a good thing to keep in mind, thanks.

Comment: I find out that `call` isn't good option cause you can't use it in comparing values.

Comment: @Timo: Fair enough. Undoubtedly, *grawity*'s suggestion is more universal than this one.